# Accented characters in Meteor

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I'm working on adding accented character compatibility to my Meteor app, and have run into several problems. While trying to troubleshoot something, I realized I can't even get the character codes to work when coming from helpers in JavaScript. When I run the following code:

html:

```
<template name="home">
<p>
This is &aacute; t&eacute;st
<br>
{{testChar}}
<br>
</p>
</template>
```

JavaScript:

```
Template.home.helpers({
testChar: function(){
//testArray = ["this is &aacute; t&eacute;st"];
//return testArray[0];
return "This is &aacute; t&eacute;st";
}
})
```

I see this:

> This is á tést 
>   This is &aacute t&eacutest
>   (the semicolons do show up on the webpage as well, I just removed them so that this text editor wouldn't display the same thing twice (which is exactly what I'm trying to get my website to do).

Thanks for any help

Comment: `{{{testChar}}}` - try this

Comment: Yep, that fixed the problem - thanks! On to the next issue...